# Ms Access generate quote number after submit in form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

How can i do to generate id number when i click on submit button in the form?

like northwind sample service database of quote form

- not much knowledge of vba

Answer (score 0):

You can generate it just "like northwind sample service database of quote form"

Comment: that's what i m asking how can i do i m beginner in Ms-access

Comment: you can look into code inside sample, it is much more useful, i suppose.